# SQL: Combine four "where" clauses on the same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I´m currently struggling to get this to work.

```
SELECT        Y, SUM(N) AS sumDK, NULL AS sumFI, NULL AS sumNO, NULL AS sumSE
FROM            stat
WHERE        (C = 'Denmark')
GROUP BY Y
UNION ALL
SELECT        Y, NULL AS sumDK, SUM(N) AS sumFI, NULL AS sumNO, NULL AS sumSE
FROM            stat
WHERE        (C = 'Finland')
GROUP BY Y
UNION ALL
SELECT        Y, NULL AS sumDK, NULL AS sumFI, SUM(N) AS sumNO, NULL AS sumSE
FROM            stat
WHERE        (C = 'Norway')
GROUP BY Y
UNION ALL
SELECT        Y, NULL AS sumDK, NULL AS sumFI, NULL AS sumNO, SUM(N) AS sumSE
FROM            stat
WHERE        (C = 'Sweden')
GROUP BY Y
```

This query gives me a matrix like this:

```
Y | sumDK | sumFI | sumNO | sumSE
----------------------------------
2011| 25 | NULL | NULL | NULL 
2012| 5 | NULL | NULL | NULL 
2011| NULL | 18 | NULL |NULL 
2012| NULL | 5 | NULL |NULL 
......
```

How can I perform a query that only returns the fields NOT NULL?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't want the columns that only have NULLs to appear?

Comment: Why not just have three columns, one for year, one for the sum, then a string column which tells you the sum type?

Comment: Hi zimdanen! I only want to receive two rows: 2011 and 2012 where I have 8 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go through the table once, and create it as a cross-tab by summing the match of respective columns

```
select
      Y,
      SUM( IIF( C = 'Denmark', N, 0 )) as SumDenmark,
      SUM( IIF( C = 'Finland', N, 0 )) as SumFinland,
      SUM( IIF( C = 'Norway', N, 0 )) as SumNorway,
      SUM( IIF( C = 'Sweden', N, 0 )) as SumSweden,
      sum( N ) totalSumValue,
      count(*) totalEntries
   FROM 
      STAT
   WHERE
      C IN ( 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Norway', 'Sweden' )
  GROUP BY 
      Y
```

Comment: Hi DRapp! Thanks, this gets closer to what I want. But your query returns the number of entries in the table for the respective years and country, but not the sum of the entries.

Comment: @user1204121, then I just added a COUNT(*) for the grand total of all countries, and changed from 1 to "N" for sum purposes

Comment: Thanks a lot! That´s exactly what i needed! (actually I don´t need totalSumValue and totalEntries). You just saved my evening :-)

Comment: @user1204121, as additional courtesy to those helping, and others who might in future.  Click the checkbox next to the answer that solved your problem.  This way others know its solved and don't need to keep posting...

Comment: Ok just "accepted" the answer. Hope that was what you meant. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1204121, yes, otherwise people are not sure its been "solved".

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT      Y, C, SUM(N) 'Sum'
FROM        stat
WHERE       C IN ( 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Norway', 'Sweden' )
GROUP BY    Y, C
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to name them all differently?  what about

```
SELECT        Y, SUM(N) AS sum, C
FROM            stat
WHERE        (C = 'Denmark')
GROUP BY Y
UNION ALL
SELECT        Y, SUM(N) AS sum, C
FROM            stat
WHERE        (C = 'Finland')
GROUP BY Y
UNION ALL
SELECT        Y, SUM(N) AS sum, C
FROM            stat
WHERE        (C = 'Norway')
GROUP BY Y
UNION ALL
SELECT        Y, SUM(N) AS sum, C
FROM            stat
WHERE        (C = 'Sweden')
GROUP BY Y
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is necessary to name them all differently :(

Answer (score 0):

Best guess - I don't have Access handy to try - using [TRANSFORM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956.aspx):

```
TRANSFORM SUM(N)
  SELECT Y FROM STAT
  GROUP BY Y
  ORDER BY Y
  PIVOT C
```